# How to start mysqld with read-only data directory?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, read-only-database

I'm trying to start MariaDB in a docker container, using a data directory from the host mounted read-only. MySQLd is of course shut down on the host. Unfortunately, even with adding the `read_only` flag to my.conf, I get the following errors:

```
root@2380610236d1:/# mysqld --innodb-read-only
140807 19:19:38 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/2380610236d1.lower-test
140807 19:19:38 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
140807 19:19:38 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Can't create file' when trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control'
140807 19:19:38 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
140807 19:19:38 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140807 19:19:38 [Note] InnoDB: Started in read only mode
140807 19:19:38 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
140807 19:19:38 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140807 19:19:38 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140807 19:19:38 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140807 19:19:38 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140807 19:19:38 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
140807 19:19:38 [Note] InnoDB: Disabling background IO write threads.
140807 19:19:38 [Warning] InnoDB: Unable to open "./ib_logfile0" to check native AIO read support.
140807 19:19:38 [Warning] InnoDB: Linux Native AIO disabled.
140807 19:19:38 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
140807 19:19:38 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-08-07 19:19:38 7f2bc5a247c0  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
140807 19:19:38 [ERROR] InnoDB: os_file_get_status() failed on './ibdata1'. Can't determine file permissions
140807 19:19:38 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
140807 19:19:38 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140807 19:19:38 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140807 19:19:38 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
140807 19:19:38 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
Couldn't start tokudb because some other tokudb process is using the same directory [/var/lib/mysql/] for [environment]
140807 19:19:38 [ERROR] Plugin 'TokuDB' init function returned error.
140807 19:19:38 [ERROR] Plugin 'TokuDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140807 19:19:38 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140807 19:19:38 [ERROR] Aborting

140807 19:19:38 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

How can I start the database server with a read-only data directory?

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I'd like to do this exact same thing to inspect database backups.

Answer (score 4):

Please note the InnoDB Architecture (Pictorial Representation by Percona CTO Vadim Tkachenko)

[image: InnoDB Architecture]

The system tablespace file `ibdata1` has moving parts requiring writes

- Data Dictionary
- Double Write Buffer

  - Safety Net to Prevent Data Corruption
  - Helps Bypass OS for Caching
- Insert Buffer (Streamlines Changes to Secondary Indexes)
- Rollback Segments
- Undo Logs

It's good you have [**--innodb-read-only**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_read_only) set to InnoDB handle read-only situations.

You also need to make sure [innodb_change_buffering](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_change_buffering) is 0.

You also needed to make sure that crash recovery never happens. Here is how to set  it up.

First, with the database on a writeable media, login to MySQL and run this:

```
mysql> set global innodb_fast_shutdown = 0;
```

Then, go to the OS and run

```
service mysql stop
```

With [**innodb_fast_shutdown**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_fast_shutdown) enabled, this cause mysqld to purge everything and its grandmother out of the InnoDB plumbing upon shutdown.

Next, move the datadir to the readonly media.

Then, add this to `my.conf`

```
[mysqld]
innodb_change_buffering = 0
innodb_read_only = 1
```

Finally, go start mysql with `service mysql start` and InnoDB should start very quickly because there will be no need to perform crash recovery since everything was purged out of the InnoDB plumbing beforehand.

Comment: `innodb_read_only` was introduced in mysql 5.6 in case someone wonders why they get `unknown variable 'innodb_read_only=1'` error.